# The measures induced by brownian motions are singular

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are measures on $C[0,1]$ induced by $c_1W_t$ and $c_2W_t$ respectively where $0<c_1<c_2$ and $W_t$ is a brownian motion.  We want to show that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are mutually singular.  it seems natural to let $A_i=\{ f \in C[0,1] : V^2(f)=c_i^2 \}$ where $V^2$ is the quadratic variation.  We know that $V^2(c_iW_t)=c_i^2$ so it would seem like $P_1(A_1)=1$ and $P_1(A_2)=0$, however I am not sure how to prove it.  We also need to prove that the $A_i$ are measurable and I'm not sure where to proceed.

Comment: If you only want this result, it may be easiest to work with the quadratic variation limit on the nested sequence of dyadic partitions. For such partitions, you can compute by hand using the Borel Cantelli lemma that the limit defining the quadratic variation is almost sure, rather than worrying about measurability of the map sending a stochastic process to its quadratic variation.